# EE 2.7.1 Publish Layout fields disappearing

Tags: ee2, custom-fields, publish-layout, custom

So I upgraded to EE 2.7.1 and I am having issues with my publish layouts. If I leave things well alone, all seems good in the world. However, if I go in and edit the layout to rearrange fields in a more friendly manner, they disappear when I go in to publish a new entry or edit an existing entry.

Very basic... If I split the difference between title and url_title, save the layout, exit the  entry, go back into the entry or create a new entry, the url_title is gone and a blank box is sitting on the "eyeball" icon in the toolbar.

Has anyone else run into this? How the heck do you fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of bugs with publish layouts that have popped up in 2.7.1. Here's a link to one that sounds like it might be related and contains a fix file to download and apply:

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19738

Let us know if that fix works for your issue as well.

Comment: On the bug page Stephen linked to above is a .zip file with a patch. It will fix this issue for you. Did for me!

Comment: That appeared to do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: One more question about this. How do you "revive" the existing entries effected? I have about 132 entries that the url_title field disappeared on and need it back.