# Restoring publish layouts after fixing the disappearing fields bug

Tags: ee2, fields, publish-layout, bug

So I had a post [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14265/ee-2-7-1-publish-layout-fields-disappearing). I got the answer I needed and applied the fix, but I can't fix the existing fields from prior entries. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that logging off, clearing the cache and logging back in did the trick. I just needed to rebuild the publish layouts after that. I don't know what I did different this time, but it's working now.